# How to insert a slider of 5 images on each article pages (selected article) in joomla

Tags: joomla, slider, flexslider, article

I am new to Joomla.
I am working on a Joomla website for a construction company.

I have created pages for each projects of the company as article page with following regions:

1. Project Title [article/page title]
2. Banner Slider [5 images of particular project using any slider]
3. Project Description
4. An image of the Project Plan.

My requirement is:

How can I insert the slider pluggin into each article page to have my second region working (BANNER SLIDER). I cant do it globally because for each project/article page the whole 5 images differ.

Thanks in advance for any sort of lead.

Comment: Is this a plugin or module? I know you said plugin but a lot of people seem to get confused

Comment: I'd suggest you to use widgetkit, http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit/downloads

Comment: @di3sel - For a simplistic slider, I would not suggest using Widgetkit. I think it's brill but only if you want to make full use it it. I've even uninstalled it on my site as I was just getting sick and tired of it :/

Comment: @Lodder Sorry it was the module to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as it's a module and not a plugin, what you can do is duplicate the module and assign each one to different articles.

To do this, go to your Module Manager, select the module and click "Copy". Not sure what the slider module is called but I assume you can select which images you wish to use, so be sure to do this for each one. You then need to give each module a custom position. Simply type one in rather that selecting one.

And finally, in each article, you can call a specific module by adding the following code:

```
{loadposition XXX}
```

where **XXX** is the position you have assigned to your module.

Hope this helps

Comment: ofcourse it helps. Thank you @lodder for this great and simple idea

Answer (score 0):

Use the Slideshow CK module, which can be found here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/20362

We use it for our clients and they all love it. It also works right out of the box.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. Will it be possible to have different set of images for each article page. I have tried with **VikSLider**. But I was able to set images to the slides only in the module manager for one set. So the same set of images were shown in all the article pages. But that should not be in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Widgetkit component and create custom slide show for each article and show each article slider in article with Widgetkit short code.